# Why does Mysql keep telling me there is an unknown column even though I've declared the alias?

Tags: mysql

I have this mySQL query here which is supposed to give me the count of all the friends of a user. However, I need to further filter this to only include confirmed friend requests which are designated by 'status = 20'.
When I try to do this in the WHERE clause, I keep getting the following error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'f.status' in 'field list'.

My query is here:

```
Select
  u.uuid, u.nick,
  count(distinct f.friend_uuid) as number_of_friends, f.status
From
  user u
    Left Outer Join (
      Select user_uuid, friend_uuid from user_friend 
      Union All
      Select friend_uuid, user_uuid from user_friend 
  )  as f
    On u.uuid = f.user_uuid
    WHERE f.status = '20'
 GROUP BY 1,2,4
    HAVING number_of_friends >=10;
```

Comment: Could you kindly format your code and put it in a codeblock? It's hard to read in this text format!

Comment: your f subquery returns two columns: user_uuid and friend_uuid.  Do you mean to be selecting status in the subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query has 3 issues.

1. You can use alias in this way. Alias will be created after creation of result set. REsult set wiill use the HAVING CLause. So, the having clause must have the name in result set. This is corrected in below query.
2. You have used WHERE f.status = '20'. f is used as LEFT OUTER JOIN. If you use ouer join column in where clause then it will become inner join.This is corrected in below query.
3. The inner query with left outer join doesn't have status column in select. Therefore it is throwing error.

   Select u.uuid, u.nick, count(distinct f.friend_uuid) as number_of_friends, f.status
   From user u
   Left Outer Join
   (
   Select user_uuid, friend_uuid, **[STATUS_COLUMN REQUIRED]** from user_friend
   Union All
   Select friend_uuid, user_uuid, **[STATUS_COLUMN REQUIRED]** from user_friend
   )  as f  On u.uuid = f.user_uuid and f.status = '20'
   GROUP BY 1,2,4
   HAVING  count(distinct f.friend_uuid) >=10;

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Hi Amit,

After posting this - I realized my own error and recreated my query in the same way as you did. But thank you for the solution, regardless!